# Is the pulse voltage MNA matrix stamp the same as a normal DC voltage?

Tags: simulation, pulse, transient, nodal-analysis, newton-raphson

I am currently doing research on circuit simulators and trying to understand their techniques for simulating specific components. Now, I am at the state of trying to do transient simulation using Jacobian, Newton-Raphson and Backward-Euler methods. I have been trying to find a matrix stamp for pulse voltage but cannot find any. This is the matrix stamp for a normal DC voltage source:

[image: DC Voltage Source]

Is it just the same as a normal DC voltage source?

Comment: It's been several years since I coded a simulator, so I'd hesitate to answer this.  However, I would recommend Farid Najm's book "Circuit Simulation" if you don't have it: https://www.amazon.com/Circuit-Simulation-Farid-N-Najm/dp/0470538716/ref=sr_1_1?crid=8L8OWZ2LRBIJ&keywords=farid+najm&qid=1666728620&sprefix=farid+najm%2Caps%2C204&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.18ed3cb5-28d5-4975-8bc7-93deae8f9840

Comment: Why do you assume the pulse is supposed to have a different matrix?